# How can I add a button in "My downloadable products" in customer dashboard that can only be enabled after an hour of order creation in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, downloadable

This screenshot is for "My downloadable products" section in customer dashboard:
[image]
According to above screenshots I have added "Test" button and right now I am keeping this button disabled

I am using Magento 2.2.3

I want to enable this button after 1 day or let's say 1 hour of order creation date(which is 29/9/2018 given in the screenshots). So how can I achieve this.

I have edited below file:

> app/design/frontend/My_vendor/my_theme/Magento_Downloadable/templates/customer/products/list.phtml

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Customer\Products\ListProducts
 */
?>

<?php $_items = $block->getItems(); ?>
<?php if (count($_items)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper downloadable-products">
        <table id="my-downloadable-products-table" class="data table table-downloadable-products">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Downloadable Products') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order #') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Title') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Download Link') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Support') ?></th>
                    <?php /*?><th scope="col" class="col status"><?=  __('Status') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col remaining"><?=  __('Remaining Downloads') ?></th><?php */?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id">
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getOrderViewUrl($_item->getPurchased()->getOrderId()) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('View Order')) ?>">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getPurchased()->getOrderIncrementId() ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_item->getPurchased()->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Title')) ?>" class="col title">
                        <strong class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Download Link')) ?>" class="col id">
                        <?php if ($_item->getStatus() == \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link\Purchased\Item::LINK_STATUS_AVAILABLE): ?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDownloadUrl($_item) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Start Download')) ?>" class="action download" <?= $block->getIsOpenInNewWindow() ? 'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"' : '' ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getLinkTitle()) ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Test')) ?>" class="col id">
                        <button type="submit" title="test" class="" disabled="disabled"><span>Test</span></button>
                    </td>
                    <?php /*?><td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?=  __(ucfirst($_item->getStatus())) ?></td><?php */?>
                    <?php /*?><td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Remaining Downloads')) ?>" class="col remaining"><?=  $block->getRemainingDownloads($_item) ?></td><?php */?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getChildHtml('pager')): ?>
        <div class="toolbar downloadable-products-toolbar bottom">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('pager') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have not purchased any downloadable products yet.') ?></span></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="secondary">
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="action back">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Back') ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So which condition I have to add in order to enable the button after certain period of time of order creation?

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai Now I want to add a particular product in cart when clicking on "Test" button?
So do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the below file:

> /vendor/magento/module-downloadable/view/frontend/templates/customer/products/list.phtml

to your theme location like below:

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Downloadable/templates/customer/products/list.phtml

And put the below contents to your **list.phtml**:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Customer\Products\ListProducts
 */
?>
<?php $_items = $block->getItems(); ?>
<?php 
    $to = date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); echo '<br>'; // current time
    $from = strtotime('-1 hour', strtotime($to));
    $from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from); // 1 hour before
?>
<?php if (count($_items)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper downloadable-products">
        <table id="my-downloadable-products-table" class="data table table-downloadable-products">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Downloadable Products') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order #') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Title') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Status') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col remaining"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remaining Downloads') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col support"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Support') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id">
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getOrderViewUrl($_item->getPurchased()->getOrderId()) ?>"
                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('View Order')) ?>">
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getPurchased()->getOrderIncrementId() ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_item->getPurchased()->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Title')) ?>" class="col title">
                        <strong class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?></strong>
                        <?php if ($_item->getStatus() == \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link\Purchased\Item::LINK_STATUS_AVAILABLE): ?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDownloadUrl($_item) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Start Download')) ?>" class="action download" <?= $block->getIsOpenInNewWindow() ? 'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"' : '' ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getLinkTitle()) ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __(ucfirst($_item->getStatus())) ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Remaining Downloads')) ?>" class="col remaining"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getRemainingDownloads($_item) ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Support')) ?>" class="col remaining"><button <?php if($_item->getPurchased()->getCreatedAt()>$from){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>>Test</button></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getChildHtml('pager')): ?>
        <div class="toolbar downloadable-products-toolbar bottom">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('pager') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have not purchased any downloadable products yet.') ?></span></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="secondary">
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="action back">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Back') ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added a logic for 1 hour. You can change it according to your requirement.

```
$from = strtotime('-1 hour', strtotime($to));
$from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from); // 1 hour before
```

This is the section where you can change the logic.